# Builtin terminal app seems to be eating some character sequences on clipboard paste

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

I am trying to paste a string  `blah.cjijjepceyd6.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com` into the `Terminal.app` but what actually shows up is  `blah.cjiyd6.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com`.  When that string is pasted to `vi` it is uncorrupted.  What might be going on during the clipboard copying to the `Terminal` ?

Comment: Do you know what the origin and destination text encodings are? Maybe this is a charset interpolation issue?

Comment: It is plain text for sure.  It is copied directly from aws console and then for good measure I have also verified by copying it to plain old vi.  The strings do just fine in vi. So either copying from the console or from vi both have the same corrupted result. I am convinced there is some processing of the characters happening when pasting to the Terminal

Comment: I guess that is possible. I have been routinely pasting large amounts text into Terminal.app for years though, and don't recall that ever happening to me. Just trying to think what might be different in your case.

Comment: Can you run `bash --norc --noprofile` and paste into that shell (just to check whether it is caused by something in your .bashrc etc). Press Ctrl-D afterwards to exit again.

Comment: @nohillside  Thx - that gave same result: collapsed/omitted characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to the `~/.inputrc`  . I had the following keystroke in there:

```
"jj": vi-movement-mode
```

The base36 encoded dns name from aws happened to contain `jj`.  I have commented out the `jj` from my `~/.inputrc` to resolve